# How to move a <tr> input one row down and delte old row (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im not into JQuery and dont know how to solve this.

I have a long table. It looks like this:

```html
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rvtmsq34/1/

and i need it to look exactly like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/rvtmsq34/

Its important, that the Month moves one `<td>` down. This was just an example.

Comment: Are you unable to modify the source directly instead of doing this with javascript?

Comment: that was quite a question :D @Taplar

Comment: I'm just saying, some people get it in their head that everything has to be done with javascript.  You gotta check them, :)

Comment: hahaha i agree with you on that, waiting for @Duk 's reply

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off modifying the HTML directly or ajusting whatever script that is outputting the HTML. However if this is not possible then below is one way of doing it.

I'm storing the month html and outputting it in to the next row. I then remove the odd rows.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Select every even tr, then select the first element inside that tr and then store the text in a variable.
  var month = $('tr:nth-child(2n) > td:first-child').html();
  // Select every even tr starting from the second row, then select the first element inside that tr and output the stored text stored in the month variable.
  $('tr:nth-child(2n+1) > td:first-child').html(month);
  // Remove every even row
  $('tr:nth-child(2n)').remove();
});
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: While that works great on this specific and small use case, if there is any variation in the pattern it won't work. On a side note, you should consider using $(function () {}) instead of $(document).ready(function() {})

Comment: It is just a basic example, that hopefully they can work with. I always use document ready for noobies because it is more readable, however I agree $(function () {}) is the recommended method.

Answer (score 0):

**You should just edit the HTML directly.**

Doing this in JavaScript would require an enormous amount of configuration and would involve regex's and many other "tricks" to get it to work. That being said, if your pattern is exactly the same every time WizardCoder's answer above is the way to go.